# ¿Es posible hacer operaciones matematicas(Sumas/Divisiones) con los footers de diferentes tablas entre si? Datatable js

Tags: javascript, datatables

Buen día :)
Quisiera saber si se pueden hacer  operaciones con los footers de diferentes tablas
ya que tengo varias tablas y a veces los resultados se dividen entre otros resultados de otras tablas:

[image]

Este es mi código general que tengo en todas las tablas para obtener resultado de un footer:

```
  return $('#' + dg).DataTable({
    "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
        var api = this.api(), data;
        var intVal = function (i) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ? i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 : typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
        };
        var Total = api
            .column(1)
            .data()
            .reduce(function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0);
        var Total2 = api
            .column(3)
            .data()
            .reduce(function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0);

        var FormatDatos = $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '').display;

        //$(api.column().footer()).html ('Total') 
        $(api.column(3).footer()).html(FormatDatos(Total2));
        $(api.column(1).footer()).html(FormatDatos(Total));


    },
```

Espero ser claro con el problema Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Hola Buen día Ingeniero.

Ha pensado en enviar el valor de ambas tablas a otra función js para poder hacer los operativos necesarios?

Saludos.

Comment: por ejemplo?   guardar  `Total` Como variable global  y en otra función utilizar esa variable para sumarla con otra variable y mostrarla en otra tabla?

Comment: De paso cheque mi ultima pregunta del foro xdxdxd

Comment: si, total guardarla a otra variable junto con las demas a usar y en otra funcion hace los calculos necesarios y ya nomas muestras cada uno donde va, y ando revisando su pregunta del validator

Comment: Ala otra pregunta ya cheque y es porque BootstrapValidator no es compatible con bootstrap4